# KDE start Screen becomes unresponsive

Tags: login, kde

I installed KDE alongside unity. The KDE worked perfectly, and then I updated my Ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu 15.04. After two times usage my KDE whenever I log in, the screen becomes unresponsive and does not log in.
Can I do something to fix this from my unity desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an update present in the [Kubuntu Backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=vivid). It could fix this bug. In theory.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```